# AWS Aurora Serverless V2 - Can it replicate snapshots cross-region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-aurora-serverless

I recently migrated to AWS Aurora Serverless V2 Cluster. Automatic Snapshot creation is working fine. However, I cannot see an option to replicate the snapshots cross-region.

The AWS Docs are once again unclear in this regard. Am I missing something, or overlooked something?

Thanks in Advance for any help.

Comment: To replicate a snapshot to another region, use the "copy snapshot" action and set the destion region with the corresponding value. With "I cannot see an option to replicate the snapshots" do you mean that the option is not available in the console (it should be at Snapshots -> Actions -> Copy snapshot) ?

Comment: I'm looking for automated way (It was possible when using Single RDS Instance – with Aurora serverless seems to be not possible anymore). 

No, I can not see it on the console. 
What you mentioned is a manual process.